# Laravel Blade Template passing data to Vue JS component

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, vue.js

I am having a problem passing a property using Vuejs ~1.0 to a child component from a Laravel Blade template. If I pass something in plain text it works just fine, but when I try to pass a js property, array, or object it doesn't work at all. I currently have a blade file with a custom component which looks like this:

`<my-component video="@{{ stuff }}"></my-component>`

If I leave out the `@{{ }}` the only thing that will be passed is the string `stuff`, and if I leave out the `@`, I obviously get a blade error, but if I use `@{{ stuff }}`, then all I get is the string `{{ stuff }}`. I'm obviously missing something, but can't tell where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look like I just figured it out, it seems that I was missing the colon before video, so it should have appeared like so:

`<my-component :video="stuff"></my-component>`

Answer (score 10):

If you are passing a **variable** to the component, then use:

```
<my-component :video= "{{ json_encode($stuff) }}" ></my-component>
```

Don't forget the *double quotes* or the result would be unpredictable for things like objects.

Answer (score 5):

If you are passing model then do this:

```
<my-component :video="{{ $stuff->toJson() }}" inline-template></my-component>
```